# calculate value string that is in a list

Tags: google-sheets, datatables

Data:

Row A

House;Farm;Zoo

House;Farm

House, Zoo

Row B

Dog;Cat;Lamb;Tiger

Dog;Bunny;Chicken,Fish

Lizard;Cat;Cow

*Table 1*
**House**
Dog
Cat
Mouse
Fish
Chicken

*Table 2*
**Zoo**
Tiger
Bear
Seal

*Table 3*
**Farm**
Bunny
Duck
Lamb
Cow
Horse

**Question** **In Google Sheets**
Ok I am trying to figure out how to calc the Column A  based on what string is in the Column B  The definition of what is in the B Column comes form the three tables in the bottom. Any help would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is one way. In some other region of the table, from which you will copy column A at the end, set up the following expression for each row, starting in column B. I am imagining your =original list with column A to be calculated starts in row 1 (so B1 is dog, C1 is cat, and so on).
Suppose your 3 tables sit in rows 6 to 8.

Some rows below, in column A, paste the following:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"",IFERROR(QUERY($A$6:$F$8,"Select A where "&"(B = '"&B1&"') OR " & "(C= '"&B1&"') OR "& "(D= '"&B1&"') OR "& "(E= '"&B1&"') OR (F='"&B1&"')")))
```

Let me unpack that. If the entry is blank, we will leave the corresponding item empty. Similarly, if our query fails, leave it blank. But the query says look in the tables, find the match, and give us the corresponding column A value.

Drag this formula right 3 more columns for a total of 4, which is the longest length of animal list we're trying to cover. You end up with the corresponding places (if any), cell by cell. Also drag this formula down 2 more columns so you get each row.

Clinch by doing the following one column further over. I was in row 10, your row may vary.:

```
=textjoin(";",true,transpose(unique(transpose(A10:D10))))
```

this puts togethjer a list of the unique, noempty, values, separated by semicolons.
Drag this down 2 columns, and then go back let you A1=the top corresponding entry, drag down, and you're set.

EDIT: The above assumes Dog, Cat, Lamb, and Tiger are spread across cells in columns B, C, D, and E. If not and they are in just one cell, you may need something like in the C column `=split(B1,";")` and to adjust columns in my formulas over by 1.

Comment: Can you attach  or share a example?  this is great thanks.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13SeROv5i8gvGmBBwLU3OkBZCPhpXSg__o59ld4zTkgI/edit?usp=sharing is a link to view a version of it. I will not leave it up forever.

Comment: If it worked, please accept it as an answer. If not, please explain what did not.